# error in generating response from PerlInputFilterHandler

Tags: perl, filter, response, mod-perl, mod-perl2

I just have one filter in my location tag of httpd.conf:

```
<Location /testproj/A>
SetHandler modperl
PerlInputFilterHandler MyApache2::Test
</Location>
```

Test is an PerlInputFilterHandler.

If I've following code in this filter:

```
package MyApache2::Test10;

use strict;
use Apache2::Const qw(OK);
use Apache2::Filter ();
use Apache2::RequestRec ();
use Apache2::RequestIO ();

sub handler {
my $f = shift; 

#my $buf = '';
#while($f->read(my $tempbuf, 1024)) {
#  $buf = $tempbuf;
#}

my $r = $f->r; 
$r->content_type("text/html\n\n"); 
$r->print("welcome!!!"); 

return OK;
}
1;
```

It generates response - in other words, it sends "welcome!!!" to browser.

However if I've following code (enables commented code):

```
package MyApache2::Test10;

use strict;
use Apache2::Const qw(OK);
use Apache2::Filter ();
use Apache2::RequestRec ();
use Apache2::RequestIO ();

sub handler {
my $f = shift; 

my $buf = '';
while($f->read(my $tempbuf, 1024)) {
  $buf = $tempbuf;
}

my $r = $f->r; 
$r->content_type("text/html\n\n"); 
$r->print("welcome!!!"); 

return OK;
}

1;
```

This doesn't work. The "welcome!!!" doesn't go to the browser - '404' does.

Can you suggest something here?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Is it that you have PerlInputFilterHandler MyApache2::Test in the location stanza but your package is actually  package MyApache2::Test10; ?

Answer (score 0):

You are omitting `use warnings;` from your code -- put that in and you will get more information about failing code in your error log.  Clearly something about reading the input buffer is not working.

Comment: Even if I replace use strict; with use warnings; I get same log so it doesn't help. Thanks anyway!