# filter is not working as expected

Tags: perl, filter, response, mod-perl, mod-perl2

It's about mod_perl2 filter.

Ideally a job of filter is to do something with input data & pass on the data to next filter or actual requested resource.

In my case, I've a PerlInputFilterHandler defined for a URL pattern. See below location tag:

```
<Location /testproj/AServlet>
SetHandler modperl
PerlInputFilterHandler MyApache2::Test10
</Location>
```

This filter (Test10) is supposed to change request data & pass on control to AServlet (a servlet deployed on WebLogic Server).

However, this filter is getting invoked but it's not passing control to AServlet - no matter what I write in filter. Why so?

Thanks.

Comment: The answer may depend on the contents of your PerlInputFilterHandler, especially with regards as to whether it passes the control to the next handler. Please post here a small self-contained example that exhibits the behaviour you experience.

Comment: Code is in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367000/error-in-generating-response-from-perlinputfilterhandler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `SetHandler` line. It tells Apache that the content phase of the request should be handled by mod_perl, but it sounds like you want the content phase handled elsewhere.
The PerlInputFilterHandler directive should still take effect even if the main content handler is not `modperl`.
If the content handler is being done by mod_perl you should also set a `PerlResponseHandler`